# Data on segmentation of search traffic in america

Tags: data, research

I'm working on a research project trying to understand the patterns and breakdowns of search usage and volumes in the United States.

Ideally, I would love a breakdown of search volume across topics like:

- navigational (ie just want to get to a domain link)
- news (if possible: split amongst events, celebs, politics, ...)
- sports (if possible: dig into splits of live scores, news about an athlete or a team, ... )
- finance (e.g. stock names )
- anything local (e.g. food, restaurants, places)
- people (e.g. bios)
- anytime time related (what time in nyc, sf, ...)
- anything numbers related (math/calculators)
- Other topics: immigration, legal, health/medicine, science/technology, food/recipes, code/math, politics, weather, images/video, etc.

Not sure if there is a dataset or good report somewhere that would give me insight into all these?
There seem to be a lot of keyword planning tools, which is somewhat helpful and I guess I could collect data on groups of keywords realted to the topics above, but for things like celebrity bios it would be quite difficult to group together all the data because each possible well known person is there own keyword…

Any help, direction would be appreciated! Thank you so much